# PHP script to lights up LED on Raspberry Zero Pi W

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, led

I do not know much about PHP, but I would like to ask how I should improve this script.

Adding a screenshot of my existing code, I will briefly describe.

[image: Screenshot]

The program causes the LED to turn on when the web button is pressed for the first time.

A condition must be met where it is given that the file size must be equal to 2 bytes. When the first condition is executed, a larger 4-byte number is written to the txt file.

By pressing the same button again, the second condition should be met, but there is an error that the file is overwritten, but the condition can not be fulfilled and I do not know why.

Do not you ask someone where there might be a problem or how would you possibly solve the problem you?

Here is part of the code:

```
    if(!file_get_contents("soubor.txt", 0)) {
            $soubor = fopen("soubor.txt","w+");
            $funkceled1 = 10;
            fwrite ($soubor, $funkceled1);
            fclose ($soubor);
        }

     if (isset($_GET['on1']) && file_get_contents("soubor.txt", 2)) {
                shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 14 1");
                $soubor = fopen("soubor.txt","w+");
                $funkceled1 = 1000;
                fwrite ($soubor, $funkceled1);
                fclose ($soubor);
            }
     else if (isset($_GET['on1']) && file_get_contents("soubor.txt", 4)) {
                shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 14 0");
                $soubor = fopen("soubor.txt","w+");
                $funkceled1 = 10;
                fwrite ($soubor, $funkceled1);
                fclose ($soubor);
```

Comment: Please post any code here as a formatted text, not in an image.

Comment: Btw `file_get_contents()`'s second parameter is `bool $use_include_path = FALSE`, not a number specifying length. Also you are not doing anything with the return value of the function.

Comment: I add part of the code. Do you think it could be done differently?

Comment: Yes, Its my school project and Im not very good in PHP. :D

Comment: make `fopen("soubor.txt","w+");` to `fopen("soubor.txt","a+");` w(write) to a(append) [php.net:fopen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php) **mode**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be rewritten this way:

```
$fileName = __DIR__.'/soubor.txt';
// if the file does not exist or does not contain '10' nor '1000', create it with default value '10'
if (!file_exists($fileName) || (file_get_contents($fileName) !== '10' && file_get_contents($fileName) !== '1000')) {
    file_put_contents($fileName, '10');
}
if (isset($_GET['on1']) && file_get_contents($fileName) === '10') {
    shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 14 1");
    file_put_contents($fileName, '1000');
} else if (isset($_GET['on1']) && file_get_contents($fileName) === '1000') {
    shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 14 0");
    file_put_contents($fileName, '10');
}
```

Comment: HOLY SMOKES, It works! Thanks a lot, you are my saver! :)

Comment: Please [mark my question as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - there is a check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your `gpio` binary works in detail, but maybe you can also read a value, besides writing one? Then you could make this super easy:

```
// read the current state from gpio (if 'read' is an option )
$current_state = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g read 14');

if (isset($_GET['on1']))  {
    // if it's off, turn it on, otherwise off.
    $new_state = (($current_state == '0') ? 1 : 0);
    shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 14 '.$new_state);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats the case too I think.